# Displaying error message with wpf TextBlock control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-controls

I am quit new to WPF, so pardon me for the newbie question.
I have a wpf user login form where user can enter their username and password. I also added a TextBlock element which I set visibility to hidden. When user login fail I will like to set the text block visible with a string error message from my UserAuthentication class. How can bind my the error message to my TextBlock and also set it visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `string` property like `ErrorMessage` to your `ViewModel` used as `DataContext` and set its value on error.

Then to show the message, you need to set binding on `Visibility` property on `TextBlock` using `BoolToVisibilityConverter` and bind to `bool` property on `ViewModel` (like `ShowErrorMessage`).

Comment: Very clear. Thanks guys!

Comment: A quick question, do I have to implement the BoolToVisibilityConverter in my code and if so how? Thanks

Comment: No, it's built in into framework (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter(v=vs.110).aspx). Looks like I misspelled its name though in my answer (it should be `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`).